# Infragistics Hierarchical databind in web application

Tags: infragistics

Hi We have to bind the data in web infragistics hiergrical control. so we need some code snipet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate 2 or more data sources and then add relationships and add the primary datasource to the WebGrid:

```
                dataset.Relations.Add("Flags", this.dataset.Tables[0].Columns["ParticipantID"], this.dsParticipants.Tables[1].Columns["ParticipantID"]);
            this.uwgParticipants.DataSource = ds.Table[0];
            Session["data"] = ds.Table[0];
            this.uwgParticipants.DataBind();
```